# Program not faster with threading

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading

I made a program that edits some files in a game, it read bytedata from files and stores the data in a python dict.

the files that the program read are 30+ files, all with the same type of data.

I had the program processing the files one by one, for each saving bytedata to a python data array, then following a structure I read all bytes in that file, then continue to the next file, etc.

that process takes about 1 minute to complete.

So I made threads, for each file, I made a thread that does the same at the same time for all files.

But it takes the same time, about 1 minute.

How can this be possible?

the problem is not data reading speed from HDD because that is made in less than 1 second, after that the bytedata that each thread is processing is stored in memory. why does it take so long? and why it is not faster with threading?

Another question, is normal that the python dict where I store all the info after that is very large in memory? like 3 GB?? , there are around 10k keys in the dict and each have maaaaany values.

Comment: It's right at the top in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) on threading. See the **CPython implementation detail**. You'll want to use multiprocessing for this task.

Comment: Multi threading rarely makes Python programs faster because of the GIL.

Comment: @Kraigolas it *may* be faster. Both threading and multiprocessing arent magic that you sprinkle on to code that always makes it faster

Comment: Threads might have made it faster if your program spent most of its time waiting for the reads (although asyncio would have been better in that case) or if your processing was really heavy. But given that it's about 2 seconds per file, the added overhead of threading is unlikely to give you any gains, more so due to the GIL limiting parallelism in threads. However, with the numbers you mentioned, I doubt that you'll see much of an improvement with `multiprocessing` either, since the overhead is even bigger - that will help if the files get bigger perhaps, or if you have workers processing many

Comment: Because threads all share the Python interpreter, only one of them can run at one time (for the most part), making true concurrent processing impossible, plus having to coordinate the sharing adds additional overhead — so it's not a magic bullet.

Comment: @martineau, I think you mean, true _parallel processing._ Two threads run concurrently if both start before either one of them finishes. Python threads can do that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: I meant [concurrently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) as in during the same time period. In Python threads are more like [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking) since the interpreter take turns running each of them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)

Comment: Besides the previous comments, it is also possible that you are making some mistake in your code, but we can't tell because you did not provide any

Comment: So basicly , it's not going to get any faster??? T_T, as per the comments I can confirm that seems that the interpreter is sharing the processing power with the threads.

Comment: @Kraigolas ahhh I'm reading what you mentioned about threading CPython implementation. I will try with a multiprocessing package

Comment: Yes: Python threads are bad for cpu-intensive tasks and good for I/O baund tasks. There are exceptions, if you use libraries that release or let you release the gil (numpy, numba), but they are bad for working with dicts.

Comment: I'm trying with multiprocessing package now, but I get a bizarre error from pyqt5 when I start the process, even a process calling a test function with just a print(), I get QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget, I'm trying to google what is happening now...

Comment: @SolomonSlow: The difference is that the computations aren't executed during **overlapping** time periods using threads (except in certain cases as azelcer mentions) — so there are often no performance gains.

Comment: @martineau, If my Python program creates two threads at approximately the same time, and the two threads run for a relatively long time doing CPU-bound computations, then how are they not "executed during overlapping time periods?" (i.e., how are they not _concurrent?_)  Of course, because of the GIL, they can not, during that time period, use any more CPU cycles than a single CPU can provide. (If they _could_ do that, we would call it _parallelism_ or _parallel processing._)

Comment: I changed the code to use multiprocessing, now the operation takes 20 seconds less, 40 seconds in total, BUT I had to use the Manager class to pass results from process back to main loop, and seems that the manager dicts are veeeery slow, showing the no multithreading result is instantaneous, reading the manager result dict takes like 20 seconds...

Comment: Pickling a huge dict takes some time...